# Scrape website and create objects using node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-scraping

I started learning node.js and i'm trying to scrape some web site data. 
This is my code.

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error) {
var $ = cheerio.load(body,{
ignoreWhitespace: false
});

var produsGasit =[];

    $('body').each(function(i, elem){

        produsGasit[i]={};

            //produsGasit[i]['name'] = $(elem).find('.fn').text();
            produsGasit[i]['produs'] = $(elem).find('.product').text();
            produsGasit[i]['reducere'] = $(elem).find('.product-badge').text();
            produsGasit[i]['linkProdus'] = $(elem).find('.product_link').attr('href');
            //imagineProdus = $(elem).find('.ProductImage').text();
            produsGasit[i]['descriereProdus'] = $(elem).find('.ProductDetails').text();
            produsGasit[i]['pretProdus'] = $(elem).find('.price').text();
            //console.log(name+"±"+produs+"±"+reducere+"+"+linkProdus+"+"+descriereProdus+"+"+pretProdus);
            console.log(produsGasit[i]);

            fs.appendFile('produse.json', JSON.stringify(produsGasit,null,8), function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('Saved!');
            });


          }

  )}
})
```

I want to write the information that i get in to objects. 
My problem is that when ever i run the code, it groups all the data based on the classes i used to identify the data. For example all the prices of a product are in a single key:value field.
What i wanted to do is to get each product i find on the page the title, the price and create separate objects with that data in a json file contraining all the data.

Comment: Instead of selecting 'body', you want to select the nearest containing element for each individual product. If you don't mind which URL are you requesting?

Comment: http://sports.woomie.ro/
no"www" in the begining

Comment: Here is something to help you learn. This site has a lot of great tutorials. Here is one on scraping: https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Cheerios has a [**map** API method](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#map-functionindex-element-) for mapping over matched elements.
It accepts a callback function that receives the index and a matched element and returns a result.

This callback can be used to transform the matched elements to product objects (*See* `Product` function.)

The [**get** API method](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#get-i-) has to be called to retrieve mapped values.

By selecting the closest containing element for a product, you can match a list of product at a time. *e.g.* Products in the *Noutati* section are in an unordered list where each list item has a **.new_product** class.

```
const Product = (el, $) => {
    return {
        name: $(el).find('.fn').text(),
        produs: $(el).find('.product').text(),
        reducere: $(el).find('.product-badge').text(),
        linkProdus: $(el).find('.product_link').attr('href'),
        imagineProdus: $(el).find('.ProductImage img').attr('src'),
        descriereProdus: $(el).find('.ProductDetails').text(),
        pretProdus: $(el).find('.price').text()
    };
};

request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    if (!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body, {ignoreWhitespace: false});
        const newProdusGasit = $('.new_product')
            .map((i, el) => ProductObject(el, $))
            .get();

        fs.appendFile(
            'produse.json', 
            JSON.stringify(newProdusGasit,null, 4), 
            function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Saved!');
            }
        );
    }
})
```